# Download list of pages from some domain with URL constraint

Tags: java, regex, html, wget

I need to download a list of all the pages on some domain that have specific URL endings.

For example, I have a webpage, like `http://brnensky.denik.cz/`, which is a Czech webpage with news. Every article has URL ending with post date, like `http://brnensky.denik.cz/zpravy_region/ruzova-kola-usnadni-presun-po-brne-20140418.html`.

So I would like to find the list of all URLs that begin with `http://brnensky.denik.cz/`, then whatever, and then for example `-20140418.html`. Is it possible to achieve?

I'm trying to solve this in Java, but also any other way would help.

Comment: `I'm trying to solve this in Java` then show us what you've tried and where your attempts failed.

Comment: Why Java? ie Python is better suited for this kinda task.

Answer (score 0):

Regex would be

```
^http://brnensky\.denik\.cz.*[0-9]{8}\.html
```

Logic

Beginning with URL and ending with date.html and date will be always 8 digit string.

You may have to escape '/' according to tool or Lang used to implement this expression